# How to read Ember-cli config file from addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

Is there another way besides reading config file with

```
this.container.lookupFactory('config:environment').modulePrefix;
```

inside and object initializer? Seems a bit odd to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ember 2.4.x (the LTS version which I recommend using), you can do the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from './template';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout,

  magicKey: Ember.computed.reads('config.magic.key'),
});
```

This assumes that you have set the config/environment.js file as follows:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    /* .... */

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    },

    magic: {
      key: "something awesome"
    },
  };

  return ENV;
};
```

EDIT: Adding how to get the config object below, to answer the question from @jcbvm.

For this to work, you will need to export the config in your app directory  in your addon as follows: (in your `addon_name/app/component/component_name/component.js` )

```
import config from '../../config/environment';

export default component.extend({ config });
```

Comment: Where is the `config` property coming from in your component?

Comment: @jcbvm I added instructions on how to get the `config` in the main answer.

Comment: I see, this should work within an app indeed, but not within an addon, you could therefor also use https://github.com/null-null-null/ember-get-config

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. This works within an addon. In the root of the addon, there is an `app` folder in which you can import and export the config as I have shown. Let me know if this is still confusing. I will add a more explicit reference in the answer.

Comment: Somehow the answer was not shoing the full path. I have added that in!